# How to get unity assetbundle manifest?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

[image]

Here my code:

```
AssetBundle ab = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Application.dataPath + "/uia.manifest");//get null here
AssetBundleManifest manifest = (AssetBundleManifest)ab.LoadAsset("AssetBundleManifest");
```

Comment: You, don't load the ```.manifest``` file as Asset-bundle. BTW why do you need to load ```.manifest``` file?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Using AssetBundles Natively](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Native.html) in particular the section **Loading AssetBundle Manifests** where it states

> Loading AssetBundle manifests can be incredibly useful. Especially when dealing with AssetBundle dependencies.
>
> To get a useable AssetBundleManifest object, you’ll need to load that additional AssetBundle (the one that’s **named the same thing as the folder it’s in**) and load an object of type `AssetBundleManifest` from it.
>
> Loading the manifest itself is done exactly the same as any other Asset from an AssetBundle:
>
> ```
> AssetBundle assetBundle =  AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(manifestFilePath);
> AssetBundleManifest manifest = assetBundle.LoadAsset<AssetBundleManifest>("AssetBundleManifest");
> ```

Though it is not well documented to be honest, in the examples around [`AssetBundles.LoadFromFile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFile.html) you can see that they do **not** load the `"Example.manifest"` as `AssetBundle` but rather only `"Example"` without a suffix!

So in your case it seems to be placed in `Assets/uia` and you would load this archive as AssetBundle, not a specific file in it.

```
AssetBundle assetBundle =  AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "uia"));
AssetBundleManifest manifest = assetBundle.LoadAsset<AssetBundleManifest>("AssetBundleManifest");
```

Also see the [`AssetBundle` Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html)

> “AssetBundle” can refer to two different, but related things.
>
> First is the actual file on disk. This is called the AssetBundle archive. The AssetBundle archive is a **container, like a folder, that holds additional files inside it**.

→ the manifest is a part of this archive and can only be loaded by loading the AssetBundle and then grab the manifest from it!

Answer (score 1):

The file you have to load in `AssetBundle.LoadFromFile` is the file `Assets`, which is a file that is stored in the same folder as your AssetBundle `uia`. This `Assets` file gets the same name as the folder is stored in, in this case `Assets`. Your code would be like this:

```cs
AssetBundle ab = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Application.dataPath + "/Assets");
AssetBundleManifest manifest = (AssetBundleManifest)ab.LoadAsset("AssetBundleManifest");
```